# Push a notification to another user

Tags: javascript

This question isn't a code-level issue but merely a functionality question / brainstorm.

Within my PHP script I want to send a notification to another user in real time, there's 1 way I've thought of to do this, if you know any better ones be sure to leave them in the comments!

My idea for this functionality is to insert into a databse table with the user's id and the message, then on the user's end constantly loop a select request looking for notifications corresponding to their id within $_SESSION, if it's found a message then delete it from the table and display it to the user.

This seems like it could "strain" my database and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this, it would also be much appreciated if somebody could post a javascript loop with a  3 second delay and an ajax post to a php file within it,

Thanks all,

James

Comment: A service called pubnub.com provides the infrastructure and client libraries for this exact use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a properly indexed, well-structured table, it won't be a strain to the db at all. Of course, this assumes your interval is reasonable (3 seconds you mentioned is great). That's how all real-time session-checking websites work. Those that need more than that, such as chat systems, basically anything that passes data more frequently and/or in larger packets, they use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: Yes I thought this, I would probably put it to 5 seconds because I don't need it that fast, websockets look very interesting and I'm going to do a little project on them to learn but untill now I think I'll take the database polling approach

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, the more I think this approach can be considered "old-fashioned" now that the web sockets are pretty much everywhere, but yeah, until you learn more about them, you're safe with the standard polling approach. How many users approximately do you expect on the average?

Comment: Maximum 50 so not too hard on the server

Comment: 50 requests at 5-sec interval is nothing, I'd go with that with no hesitations. I assume you use MySQL, but if you want to save more on the I/O, you can use Redis to store and read the messages (but be careful, it's not persistant).

Answer (score 2):

The cleaner way to do this would be with websockets. Polling, long polling, and streaming are going to have exactly the problem you thought you were going to have.

The message recipient needs to be listening via broadcast also through websockets. The server will notify all websockets listening for that particular event.

You don't want to block with database read and writes. Just take the action from one user and send it to all the other websockets listening for that event (the other user's client side instances)

For event history you would consider persisting to a database with a message queue.

Comment: Websockets, will look this up, can you narrow down what sort of things I should be looking for, thanks by the way for the response

Comment: @iJamesPHP "php websockets" would be a start, and then you will need a client side framework that allows opening websockets. Each browser can have it's own syntax for websockets, therefore using a [javascript] framework made for that will be productive.

Comment: I'm considering removing my answer, websockets are the future. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use [Websockets](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) or [Server-Sent-Events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

just an idea:

1. User-1 send message to the Server `{"message" : "hello", "target" : "User-2"}`
2. Server checks the message and redirect it to the target User
3. User-2 listening for events from Websocket or Server-Sent-Events